# Error when using mysql_fetch_array();

Tags: php

```
table data(id, name)
function getData() {
        $data = array();
        $sql = 'Select * From data';
        $query = mysql_query($sql);
        if(!$query) {
            echo "Error: " . mysql_error();
            exit;
        }
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
$data = $this->getData();
foreach($data as $dt) {
echo $dt->name;
}
```

I get an error when I `echo $dt->name;`, the output is null, How do I fix it ?

Comment: What exactly does the error say? Are you sure there is an open connection at this point?

Answer (score 2):

`$dt` is not an object but a array. `$dt->name` should be `$dt['name']`.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
var_dump($data);

//if its not a class then simply do
$data = getData();
```